# Sort List of objects by id from a sting List

Tags: sorting, grails

I have a grails application with Java 7. In this I have a table for List and a table for Items in the table which is shown as below. It's a many to many relationship where List is the parent, and for Normalization I have List_Item class, so the normal functionality is working as expected.

```
Class Parent{
    static hasOne{list:List}    
}

Class List{
    ....
    static hasMany{item:Item}
    static hasOne{listOrder:ListOrder}
}

Class Item{
    Long id
    .....
}
```

Now I have to store the order of the items in the list. So I created the following structure

```
Class ListOrder{
    Long id
    List list
    //Stores all the ids as a coma separated string in the necessary order
    String order
}
```

So each time the order is changed, the ListOrder record is to be updated.

Now I need a way to sort the items with the stored id Sting when I retrieve either List or the Parent classes. I was hoping to achieve this by a method in List domain object with name 'orderItems()', where when I call this method, the item parameter in List object, will be set to the sorted List object.

The idea I have in mind looks similar to the following code

```
Class List{
    ....
    orderItems(){
        this.item = this.item.sort(this.itemOrder.order.split(','))
    }
    ....
}
```

How can I achieve this, or is there a better way to achieve this? According to the requirement a List can contain over 100 items, so I opted not to store each items position individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are doing. But just sort the List?
If the items in the list are objects you can sort on any of those objects fields like so.

```
   Class obj {
     String name
     String status
     String desc
   }

   List objList = .... List of obj
   obj.sort {a, b -> a.name <=> b.name} // Sort by name
   obj.sort {a, b -> a.status <=> b.status} // Sort by status
   obj.sort {a, b -> a.desc <=> b.desc} // Sort by desc
```

Lists can store millions of items, so don't make a string.

Comment: And why all of that iterations of obj.sort ? why not  `obj.sort {a, b -> a.name <=> b.name ?: a.status <=> b.status ?:a.desc <=> b.desc }` that will do the same thing without recalling it over and over

Answer (score 0):

I have read this a couple of times and think I understand what the end user is trying to achieve and think it is some custom way they have thought of to try to manage a limited hasMany relationship.

The process is flawed and I will explain why.

By having a String field called ids that contains a list of ids. You will only ever really be able to sort the list without complex queries by the ids. Once split sorted etc. It is an amateur way of thinking of the relations.

This is why you have to first lookup the first object. Then once got iterate through own process to load up actual records for the ids that are supposed to be mapped. This means it is going to be very difficult to write a query to work seamlessly in this instance to find a specific given relation hanging off.

Instead of doing all of this you have

```
Class Example1 {
   //Would have 
  // static hasMany = [ example2:Example2]
  //but in your case
   String examples2=1,2,10000001122,33222222332222,023222434343243, 
   //and so on
}
```

So you have two choices ..

```
Class Example1 {
   //Would have 
   static hasMany = [ example2:Example2]
   static constrains= {
     example2:validator: checkExample
    }
  static def checkExample={val,obj,errors->
        if (val && val.size()>100) {
            errors.rejectValue('', "toomany.records", [''] as Object[], '')
        }
    }
}
```

above would limit to a 100 hasMany and give you seamless query access from main or reverse object if belongsTo is setup correctly for reverse.

Alternatively this is all rather straight forward if you think of it this way:

```
class Example1 {
  //nothing at all about example2 as yet


    Set<Example2> getExample2BySortedGivenField() {
       //either a set or a list that then you write your HQL 
       // or some specific query to return object by given sorting
        return Example2.findAllByExample(this)

    }

   //you can have a few different onces if needed or a dynamic method that passes in what to sort by - the output will be what you have asked for in question

}
```

Now in class Example2 you simply bind in main class

```
class Example2 {
  //Simply bind the primary object in example2 class no need to do 
  // additional work in example2 to manage beyond query
  Example1 example1
}
```